# Using the same label in a procedure and incrementing labelframe row

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to be able to increment the row in a labelframe by pressing a button.

I have tried the below code but it doesn't seem to work. I think it might be because I'm using the same label. I tried manually putting the same variable in rows 0 and 1 and it only shows in row 0, so not sure whats happening.

Incrementing $add_row is working with puts before and after putting the label in the row.

```
global newrow 
set newrow 1
tk::labelframe .ss -text "Sequence Select" -pady 10
tk::label .ss.seq_no_lb -text "Seq #" -justify center -width 5
tk::button .enter -borderwidth 1 -height 1 -text "Enter" -width 5 -command    incrow
pack .enter 

proc incrow {} {
    global newrow
    place .ss -x 0 -y 0
    puts "row before new grid is $newrow"
    grid .ss.seq_no_lb -row $newrow 
    incr newrow
    puts "row after new grid is $newrow"
}
```

Any ideas?

EDIT - Probably's better if I explain what I want to do.

The attached image is what the app looks like so far.

The idea is to turn on a series of relays choosen by checkboxes.
(1) You choose the first sequence, press enter and the x's turn to either 1's or 0's 
(2) to add another sequence, press add which will create another row called Seq 2 and will show x's
(3) You then start the sequence
(4) each sequence will have a user selectable time each sequence should run for.

[image: App]

Comment: Wow, using 3 different geometry managers in only 15 lines of code!

Your code does move the label to ever increasing row numbers (remember, `grid .ss.seq_no_lb` is shorthand for `grid configure .ss.seq_no_lb`). But that leaves the old row empty, which reduces its height to 0. So you don't see a difference.

It is not entirely clear to me what you expected to happen. In any case, each widget can only be in one place at a time.

Comment: ok cheers Schelte, I have updated my question with details of what I want to do.

Comment: If you really want to do it with labels, you will need to create labels with unique names for each row and column. But I would suggest to switch to ttk::treeview or tablelist for showing the sequence. Those will also make it easy to add a scrollbar if the list gets long.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are more easy alternatives but it's possible to do. For example,

```
set Rows 10
set newrow 0
grid [labelframe .ss -text "Seq #" -pady 10 -height 200 -width 50  -bg green]
for {set i 0 } { $i < $Rows } {incr i} {
     grid rowconfigure .ss $i -weight 1 -uniform 1
}

grid propagate .ss 0
label .ss.seq_no_lb -bg red
grid [button .enter -borderwidth 1 -height 1 -text "Enter" -width 5 -command incrow]

proc incrow {} {
    global newrow Rows
    .ss.seq_no_lb configure -text "Seq $newrow"
    grid .ss.seq_no_lb -row  $newrow    
    incr newrow
    if {$newrow  == $Rows} {
    .enter configure -state disabled
    }
}
```

The secrets are

1. Propagate to zero
2. Apply the weigth for each row

on this way grid will reserve the space for each row to be occupied for the label.

Saludos,